# How to find the opposite numerator of a fraction?

Tags: fractions

I'm attempting to write an algorithm that deals with colors for a video game, and I've come across a very simple problem that I can solve no problem, but have no idea how to write a foolproof function that works for any input.

What I need to do is find the opposite numerator given a fraction.

For example, I have $\frac {184}{255}$ The opposite would be $\frac {71}{255}$.

If I have $\frac {13}{100}$ the opposite would be $\frac {87}{100}$
$\frac {0}{100}$ is $\frac 11$ and $\frac {100}{100}$ is $\frac {0}{100}$.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look
at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE if you need to do so. 
Furthermore, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding opposite (as you defined) just subtract it from $1$.

As your examples say: $1- 184/255 =  (255-184)/255 =71/255$.